# Div Inside NavBar 100% Height Not Working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

need your help here. The container inside the navbar (the one in red) I want its height to be 100%. It should touch the top and bottom of its parent container. However, I am unable to do so. The image on the left is kind of causing the problem here. If I remove the image, then that is exactly how I want the height to be. But I also want the image. How can I achieve its 100% 
height with the image on its left?

Below is the JFiddle link-
[JFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/7zy0kb3e/)

```
body
        .container-fluid
            .container
                nav.navbar.navbar-toggleable-md.navbar-light.bg-faded.row
                    button.navbar-toggler.navbar-toggler-right(type='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#navbarSupportedContent' aria-controls='navbarSupportedContent' aria-expanded='false' aria-label='Toggle navigation')
                        span.navbar-toggler-icon
                    .navbar-brand
                        img(src='img/main-logo.svg' height='60')
                    .collapse.navbar-collapse#navbarSupportedContent
                        ul.navbar-nav.ul-extension.nav-fill
                            li.nav-item.active
                                a.nav-link(href="#") Home
                            li.nav-item
                                a.nav-link(href='#') About
                            li.nav-item
                                a.nav-link(href='#') Services
                            li.nav-item
                                a.nav-link(href='#') Gallery
                            li.nav-item
                                a.nav-link(href='#') Contact
```

Comment: This isn't entirely clear - removing the image doesn't change the height of the red div. Are you referring to position of divs? Which divs are in the right place, and which div needs to be in a different position?

Comment: Okay Just ignore the Image part. I want the container (highlighted in red) to touch the parent container that is 100% height. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
.navbar-nav {line-height: 44px;}
```

Comment: Well. It worked. Can you explain why line-height does the work and not the height property of the container?

Comment: I'm not sure. The height might work as well. However the changing line-height does keep the text vertically aligned. I was overriding the line-height in the body CSS that was controlling the height of the element.